# The following code produces this error: "conflicting types for 'fptr' ."

Tags: c, file, pointers

While debugging this code I get the following error: "conflicting types for 'fptr'." This shows at 3 lines with the same piece of code. I'll just identify one line: 158 in the void list() section. I'm no expert in files. I ask if you know what's the issue if you could please intervene? Thank you in advance!!

Header file:

```
struct employee
{
        char name[50];
        char sex[7];
        char adrs[50];
        char dsgn[25];
        int age;
        int empID[9];
        float slry;
};
```

Problem:

```
     printf("-------------------------------");
     printf("\nEmployee Details: \n---------------------------------\n");
     rewind(fptr);///moves file to start of the file
     size_t fread(void *fptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *fptr)///read the file and fetch the 
     record one record per fetch
```

Entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "struct.h"

void insert();
void list();
void edit();
void del();
void exit();
int tolower();

FILE * fptr, *ftemp;
struct employee e;
size_t recsize ;
char empname[50];

int main()
{
    int choice;
    fptr = fopen("ems.txt", "r+");


    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't find file! Attempting to create file... \n");

        fptr = fopen("ems.txt","w+");
        if(fptr == NULL)
        {
            printf("Can't create file. Exiting...");
         exit(1);
        }
    }

    //Explain the reason for this?
    recsize = (long int) sizeof(e);


    while(1)
    {
        printf("*******************************\n");
        printf("\nEmployee management system");
        printf("\n1. Insert employee information");
        printf("\n2. List all employee information");
        printf("\n3. Edit employee information");
        printf("\n4. Delete employee information");
        printf("\n5. Exit");
        printf("\n\n*****************************\n");
        printf("\n\n Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        int ch;  while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;}

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                puts("Insert was chosen");
                insert();

                break;
            case 2:
                puts("List was chosen");
                list();
                break;
            case 3:
                puts("Edit was chosen");
                edit();
                break;
            case 4:
                puts("Delete was chosen");
                del();
                break;
            case 5:
                puts("Exit was chosen");
                exit(1);
                break;
            default:
                puts("Choice is incorrect!!");
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


void insert()
{
    char next;

    do
    {
        printf("********************************************************** \n");
        printf("\nEnter the name of the employee: ");
        fgets(e.name, sizeof(e.name), stdin);
        e.name[strcspn(e.name, "\n\r")] = '\0';

        printf("\nEnter the sex of the employee (M/m or F/f): ");
        scanf("%6s",e.sex);

        switch(*e.sex)
        {
            case 'M':
            case 'm':
                printf("\nMale.\n");
                break;
            case 'F':
            case 'f':
                printf("\nFemale.\n  ");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Unspecified Sex.");
        }

        printf("\nEnter the address of the employee: ");

        fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END); // ADD THIS TO AVOID SKIP

        fgets(e.adrs, sizeof(e.adrs), stdin); // this
        e.adrs[strcspn(e.adrs, "\n\r")] = '\0';

        printf("\nEnter designation of the employee: ");
        fgets(e.dsgn, sizeof(e.dsgn), stdin); // this
        e.dsgn[strcspn(e.dsgn, "\n\r")] = '\0';

        printf("\nEnter age of the employee: ");
        scanf("%d", &e.age);
        printf("\nEnter basic salary of the employee: ");
        scanf("%f", &e.slry);
        printf("\nEnter the employee's ID: ");
        scanf("%8d", e.empID);
        fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", e.name);
        fprintf(fptr, "%6s\n", e.sex);
        fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", e.adrs);
        fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", e.dsgn);
        fprintf(fptr, "%d \n%f \n%d \n", e.age, e.slry, e.empID[9]);
        fwrite(&e,recsize,1,fptr);
        int ch;  while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;}
        //fflush(stdin);//
        printf("\nDo you want to input more? (y/n): ");
        next = getche();
        printf("\n");
    }
    while( tolower(next) != 'n' );

    //fclose(fptr);
}

void list ()
{
     printf("-------------------------------");
     printf("\nEmployee Details: \n---------------------------------\n");
     rewind(fptr);///moves file to start of the file
```

L158///  size_t fread(void *fptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *fptr)///read the file and fetch the
record one record per fetch
{
printf("\n\n%s \t\t%6s \t%s \t%s \t%d \t%.2f \t%d",e.name, e.sex, e.adrs, e.dsgn, e.age,
e.slry, e.empID[9]);
return;
}
getch();

```
     /*printf("Name        : %s\n",e.name);
     printf("Address     : %s\n",e.adrs);
     printf("Sex         : %c\n",e.sex);
     printf("Designation : %s\n",e.dsgn);
     printf("Age         : %d\n",e.age);
     printf("Salary      : %.2f\n",e.slry);
     printf("Employee-ID : %d\n",e.empID);*/
}

void edit ()
{
    char next;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter the employee's name to be edited: ");
        scanf("%49[^\n]", empname);
        rewind(fptr);
        size_t fread(void *fptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *fptr)///fetch all records from file
        {
            if(strcmp(e.name,empname) == 0) ///if entered name matches with that in file
                {
                printf("\nEnter new name, sex, address, designation, age, salary and employee ID: ");
                scanf("%s%c%s%s%d%f%d", e.name, e.sex, e.adrs, e.dsgn, &e.age, &e.slry, e.empID);
                fseek(fptr, -recsize, SEEK_CUR);/// move cursor 1 step back from current position
                fwrite(&e, recsize,1,fptr); ///override the record
                break;
                }
        return ;}

        printf("\nEdit another record(y/n)");
        next = getche();
        int ch;  while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;}

    }
    while(next != 'n');

    return ;
}

void del()
{
    char next;
    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter name of employee to delete: ");
        scanf("%s",empname);
        ftemp = fopen("Temp.dat","wb"); ///create a intermediate file for temporary storage
        rewind(fptr); ///move record to starting of file
        size_t fread(void *fptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *fptr)  ///read all records from file
        {
            if(strcmp(e.name,empname) != 0)  ///if the entered record match
            {
                fwrite(&e,recsize,1,ftemp); ///move all records except the one which is to be deleted to temp file
            }
            return ;
        }

        fclose(fptr);
        fclose(ftemp);
        remove("ems.txt"); ///remove original file
        rename("Temp.dat","ems.txt"); ///rename temp file to original file name
        fptr = fopen("ems.txt", "rb+");
        printf("Delete another record(y/n)");
        int ch;  while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;}
        next = getche();


    }while( tolower(next) != 'n' );
    fclose(fptr);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: `size_t fread(void *fptr, ...` That looks like you trying to *define* a local function `fread` inside other functions. It won't work, and can't work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but what would you recommend?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean to do there, instead. If you want to read something from the file, I recommend you start with the documentation for [`fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread).

Comment: Thanks for the help. After carefully looking at the fread syntax I pointed out the error. Instead of: size_t fread(void *fptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *fptr), its, size_t fread(void *fptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream).